# Override Devise downcase_keys method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I need to override downcase_keys method from `devise/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb` :
[see](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/72cf2481b503bbdcc36f101823545680af81b1a9/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L177).

So I have an initializer in my Rails application which does that :

```
module Devise
 module Models

  module Authenticatable

   protected
   def downcase_keys
     puts "foo"
     super
   end

 end
end
```

But this overrided method is never called (when it should).

Any clue?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you restarted the server?

Comment: Didn't want to patronise, you'd be surprised how often that's the problem :D

Comment: And what you want to do with this method?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this method is now protected : 
[issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/4def6000769259ee186cc0f59608a5bd3e668eb5).

Basically I needed to do that in order to downcase user email domain but not prefixes.
Now I just added a `before_save` line in my user manager code that calls a method which does the work and I removed `:email` from `config.case_insensitive_keys`.

I also had to refactor a bit of code of my overrided `find_for_authentication` function.